# Asked vs edit in question summary

Tags: support

This question

[Internationalization of content in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085205/internationalization-of-content-in-entity-framework)

tells me in the right hand summary column that it was

- asked 1 year ago
- has 370 views
- last active 11 moNths ago

Yet if I look at the "OP box" for the question I see it was in fact "Asked" over 2 years ago in June '12, but edited about a year ago in Jun 13.

Now in the grand scheme of things is my life being adversely affected by this? No.

But still: Asked != last edited.

Comment: June 18th 2012 is not _over_ 2 years ago.

Comment: Wait 12 or 13 days and then check back. Blame it on caching.

Comment: @Mat yep fair enough. I cant count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was asked **under** 2 years ago. If you mouse-over the *1 year ago* text you'll see that the date matches the asked date:

[image]

The same applies to the *active* field; it's under 12 months ago still.

It'll show as *2 years ago* in about 2 weeks time.

Comment: Ah I see, never noticed that before. Still I read one year as being 1 year, in this case it's 1 year plus 355 days.

Comment: @rism: the relative dates are just not that verbose.